# Slow query due to timestamp order by, can't figure out how to fix

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table (logs) holding approximately 100k rows.  Each row has a timestamp associated with when it was created.  When I sort by this timestamp, even with numerous WHERE criteria, the query is much slower than without a sort.  I can't seem to find a way to speed it up.  I've tried all kinds of indexes.

The query is returning about 25k rows.  I have similar queries that need to be run, with slightly different WHERE criteria.

With the ORDER BY, the query takes 0.6 seconds.  Without the ORDER BY, the query takes 0.003 seconds.

The table structure is as follows.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `logs` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `shipment_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `time` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `initials` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `result` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `information` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `issues` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fw_actions` varchar(999) DEFAULT NULL,
  `noncompliant` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `noncompliant_lead_initials` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `noncompliant_lead_time` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `event_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `action_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `resolution_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `noncompliant_reviewed` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `violation` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `approved` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `approved_time` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `approver` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `reviewed` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `reviewed_time` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `reviewer` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `editor` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `summary` varchar(999) DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `LOGS_SHIPMENT_ID_TIME` (`shipment_id`,`time`,`action_id`),
  KEY `SHIPMENT_ID_IDX` (`shipment_id`),
  KEY `logs_updated_index` (`updated`),
  KEY `violation_idx` (`violation`,`approved`,`reviewed`,`shipment_id`,`time`,`reviewer`,`approver`,`editor`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=100022 ;
```

The query is

```
SELECT * FROM logs
WHERE (logs.approved != 1) AND (logs.violation = 1)
ORDER BY logs.`time` DESC
```

My EXPLAIN looks like this

```
id   select_type    table   type    possible_keys   key            key_len  ref    rows  Extra
1    SIMPLE         logs    ref     violation_idx   violation_idx  2        const  1000  Using index condition; Using where; Using filesort
```

Anyone have a trick here?  Thanks!

Comment: I don't know, but would using InnoDB improve this at all people?

Comment: InnoDB is slower than MyISAM, MyISAM is recommended if you don't use InnoDB features like foreign keys...
Did you try your benchmark several times, only one try means nothing.
For MySQL, 100k rows is nothing... But if you can, you could use a cache to avoid this query.

Comment: Does it improve if you add an index on `time`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key_len column says that MySQL is only using 2 bytes of the index "violation_idx".  So it's only using the first two columns, "violation" and "approved", each of which is a tinyint (one byte).

You *might* be able to improve the performance of *this query* by making "time" the third column in this index. Currently, it's the fifth column. I don't know what other queries you're doing; this kind of change might hurt performance in other queries.

Also, you *might* be able to improve the performance by creating an additional index on the "time" column alone. Both those things are worth testing.

Most dbms will benefit from an index that has a descending sort on "time", but [MySQL won't](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html).

> An index_col_name specification can end with ASC or DESC. These
>   keywords are permitted for future extensions for specifying ascending
>   or descending index value storage. Currently, they are parsed but
>   ignored; index values are always stored in ascending order.

You'll have to find your own comfort level with that. Today, creating an index "DESC" expresses your intent clearly, but a future upgrade to MySQL that starts parsing and implementing that expression might hurt performance for other queries.

Comment: Creating an index on just time took care of it.

Answer (score 0):

Create an index on just time. Further indexes can aid with additional filters in the direction of your time index.

Comment: Ahh, I see you found the answer. Sorry Aaron. Glad Time worked. :D